# Symbolic representation of Class Conditional Probablity as a variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics, variable-definitions, variable

What is the best way to a create a symbolic variable to represent Class Conditional Probability in Mathematica e.g.

$p(A|B)$

Comment: You've seen `Conditioned[]`?

Answer (score 0):

your question is very general. So i don't know if this is what you are asking

```
ClearAll[p];
SetAttributes[p, HoldAll];

check = p[#] > 0 &;
p[B] = 0.1;
p[A \[Intersection] B] = 0.05;
p[pat : p[A_], p[B_?check]] := Hold[pat/p[B]]

p[p[A \[Intersection] B], p[B]]

(*Hold[p[A\[Intersection]B]/p[B]]*)

% /. Hold -> ReleaseHold /. _p :> "p(B) is zero"

(* 0.5 *)
```

Comment: No, I am asking how to make the Class Conditional Probability (e.g. P(A|B) a symbolic variable. I understand that Mathematica doesn't allow ( or ) or |  in a variable name.